# onValue doesn't fire

Tags: javascript, bacon.js

```
$('#ddEvents').asEventStream('change').onValue(function (f) { alert('hello world'); });
```

ddEvents is a drop down list. When I change it, the onValue function doesn't fire. What am I getting wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi you code work i did a test on codepen

```
#add 2 cdn jquery bacon
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gGrNQV

Comment: @IanWarburton don't show your html about the ID using on js named : #ddEvents

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are trying to detect a change in what has been selected, this works.  Be sure you have included the jquery library correctly:

```
<select id="ddevents">
     <option value="first">First</option>
     <option value="second">Second</option>
     <option value="third">Third</option>
 </select>

$('#ddevents').change(function(){
   alert("selection had changed");
});
```